# Calculating the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm trying to understand the dynamics of the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues. My question is about formula for finding the eigenvalues. At 4:15(the athor starts the calculation at 1:30) of the given [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdsV0RaC9jM&index=1&list=LL2gry7n2BsijUeah-oFnPSg) why should the determinant of the matrix be zero?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an eigenvalue equation,

\begin{align*}
Ax=\lambda x
\end{align*}

where $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is an eigenvector, and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue. This equation is the same as

\begin{align*}
Ax-\lambda x=0\implies (A-\lambda I)x=0
\end{align*}

The goal is to find $x$ and $\lambda$. The only time when we get a nontrivial solution is when the determinant of $(A-\lambda I)$ is zero.

Comment: Is it because the matrix must have no inverse?

Comment: @Snate If $(A - \lambda I)$ is invertible then the only solution to $(A- \lambda I)x = 0$ is $x = 0$, which is precisely what we want to exclude.